# resizable Custom Window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am needing to make a custom window with WindowStyle.None, AllowsTransparency = true, etc.

and  "**resizeable**"

how con help me to create resizeable this?

tanx...

Answer (score 4):

The most simple solution is to implement the [ResizeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.resizemode.aspx) property, setting it to "CanResizeWithGrip".

```
<Window x:Class="TestProject.ScratchWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"  
        Opacity="1.0" 

        ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"

        WindowStyle="None" 
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        Title="Test Window">

    <!-- Window Contents Here -->
</Window>
```